# Pass from login a variable to know is the first time the user login

Tags: django, django-users

First time the user logins, I want to show him a multi step setup.

How can I pass from login a variable to know is the first time the user login ?

An observation:

If the user passed the multi step setup, even if is still in first login, cancel the variable for multi step setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `User` Model has [`last_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login) attribute which is a `DateTimeField`.

If the user never logged in, it is `None`.

Or give him a cookie and test it.

Comment: yes, but what about my observation ? the user finish the steps but is still on the first login